# Python - communicating with gnome-terminal

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, gnome-terminal

Through python, is there a way I can open gnome-terminal and then send commands to it, which are then run in that window? For example, where I could do something like

```
terminal.communicate("echo testing")
```

and the gnome-terminal prints the output? I've seen similar posts using subprocess Popen and communicate, although I wasn't getting the newly opened terminal to run the commands. Thanks for any help

Comment: This is similar to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/313554/how-to-control-gnome-terminal-from-python-scrypt), which in unanswered. The answered questions only seem to send one command at the start of the gnome-terminal.

Comment: the answer from the duplicate already handles it: create a named pipe and write the commands to it (how many you like).

Comment: I guess I'm missing something. I can't get the terminal to run commands from the named pipe

Comment: "Can't" is not informative. If you don't understand the answers; ask a separate  question about the specific aspects of the answer that you have an issue. Make sure to include a minimal code example that demonstrates the issue. Describe in detail what do you expect the code to do and what happens instead (step by step) -- if there are errors; paste them as is in your question. Include the link to the current question for context.

Answer (score 0):

you could do os.system to execute commands, like This

```
import os
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"sudo apt-get update; exec bash\"'")
```

Comment: Yes, but there isn't a constant connection there. Say later, I want to  automatically run some other command in that specific terminal without having the user type in a command

Comment: You can always execute multiple commands in a single line using && symbol, for example -  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I know of using &&, but I was looking for being able to control the terminal from python, not just start a terminal and run a series of commands. Perhaps I would like to push a command through later on, after some specific event. It was just a thought I had for something I was working on. I will probably just end up running whatever at the opening of the terminal. It gets the job done, but I was just thinking of this to possibly add more functionality later